# What's the determinant of $A$ with columns expressed as vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am trying to find $\det(A)$ if $a,b,c,d \in\Bbb R^4 $.
 $$\begin{bmatrix}a-b & b-c & c-d & d-a\end{bmatrix}$$
 I can't understand how to tackle this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may write the columns in different lines in your question,  so we can understand what the columns are.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. what is the $(a-b)$?

Comment: a,b,c,d are vectors in R^4

Comment: The determinant is $0$. $a-b, b-c, c-d$ and $d-a$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: How can we tell that they are linearly dependent? When we want to show the they are dependent there has to be a combination so that c1u1 +c2u2+cnun = 0 other than c1=c2=c3=...cn=0

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: Sum of the columns is $0$, so the determinant is $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Another way to approach the problem is to note that
$$
A = \pmatrix{a&b&c&d}\pmatrix{1&0&0&-1\\-1&1&0&0\\0&-1&1&0\\0&0&-1&1}
$$

Comment: I never thought of it that way, that's nice!!!